# How to globally overload assert so I don't have to change lib code in my PyQT app?

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt

My app use QT for the gui layer, and many other lib I made.

One of this other lib is quite complex (it's a type system) and full of asserts to make it as solid as possible.

But when an assert is triggered in this lib, the Qt mainloop simply continue.
I have a qt_debug() that works well (with pyqtRemoveInputHook) for the Qt part but nothing for the rest of python libraries.

And, obviously I would avoid to change code in the library as it should useable without Qt.

The best solution would be an assert hook, but despite googling around I didn't any obvious way to do it. Any idea ?

Comment: You need to accept answers for your other questions, or update them so you can get a good, useable answer.

Comment: Would like to, but so far there no good answer. No explanation of this strange behavior. I have no problem to accept one of those answers but I feel this is misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `assert` is the wrong way.  For one thing, if Python is run with -O (or -OO) `assert`s are turned off; for another, the error message is not very helpful.  That library needs to be redesigned to properly use exceptions.

As far as using the library as it stands:  what do you want to have happen?  Should your app quit?  If so, you could create your own AssertionError class, replace the one in `__builtins__` with yours, and have it do whatever you want in its `__init__`.  Note that you are completely on your own if you do this.

Comment: Assert are a good tool IMHO is  as they are a checking (type) invariants. TypeError could be used but I don't want to use the same exception as python itself, it could be confusing. Beside, IIRC the QT mainloop swallows other exceptions the same way.

Comment: Thank you, overloading the assertion error works. ( I was trying to overload the assert statement so far. without success )